# gsub - transform in uppercase first occurrence of a character

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm currently studying regex (using ruby) and I would like to find the first occurrence of a non-digit character inside a word and make it capitalized.

I've been trying with:

```
word.gsub!(/\D{0,1}/) do |w|
    w.capitalize
end
```

hoping it would just catch the first occurrence of a non-digit, but instead it returns all of the letters capitalized.
What's the correct way to do this?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `g` in [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) stands for "global," meaning "every occurrence in the string."  You want regular [`sub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-sub-21) instead.  That'll just find the first.  Cheers!

Comment: You can also shorten it to `word.sub! /\D/, &:capitalize`.